# how to design Order and Order Items resource for REST endpoints?

Tags: api, rest, http, architecture, api-design

which one should I use?

```
/api/users/{userId}/orders/items
OR
/api/users/{userId}/orderItems
```

I only got two tables: User(oneToMany) and OrderItems and I'm not sure if I need to create an entity for Order since I'm not going to use it anywhere on my application, this API will work only with GET verbs since it`s going to only read from DB, So how should I create my REST Endpoint to list all order items for a given user?
pseudo-classes:

```
    class user {
        userId;
        orderIds;
    }
    class orderItem{
        orderId;
        itemId;
        itemDesc;
        quantity;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

GET all orders - /api/users/{userId}/orders

GET specific order - /api/users/{userId}/orders/{orderId}

Reference - [best-practices-for-rest-api-design](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/02/best-practices-for-rest-api-design/)